# Why can't Perl find my module in @INC?

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm running a CGI script (which used to work but stopped working suddenly) and getting the following error message:

`Can't locate conn.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /www/my/lib, etc.)`

However, the file `conn.pm` is stored in the directory `/www/my/lib`. My CGI script has these lines at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);

use lib "/www/my/lib";
use conn;

// rest of code here ...
```

Could anyone weigh in on why I might be getting this error message? Because the @INC variable should have `/www/my/lib`, and `conn.pm` is located in that directory.

**Update:** In answer to a comment below, `conn.pm` has permissions `rwxr-xr-x` and every directory in its path has permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.

**Update 2:** In answer to another comment, here is the output from `@ikegami's` shell script.

```
$ ./diagnostic.sh
Content-Type: text/plain

USER=<user>
PWD=/home/<user>
===
/www/my/lib
/gedi/dev/lib/perl/BioPerl-1.6.1
/usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
.
===
```

**Update 3:** Okay, when I run my CGI script on its own with Perl it works, per `@ikegami's` comment. The script is called "login.cgi" and when I run `perl login.cgi` I get no errors.

The problem is when I point a web browser to my index page. The index page has a refresh which does this:

`<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=/www/my/cgi/login/login.cgi">`

Could it have anything to do with the index page which redirects to `login.cgi`?

Comment: Does the webserver user have read permissions on `conn.pm` and all of the directories in the path?

Comment: Yeah, `conn.pm` has permissions `rwxr-xr-x`, and every directory in its path has the same permissions.

Comment: What does `-e "/www/my/lib/conn.pm"` tell you, if run within the CGI environment?

Comment: What's the output of [this CGI script](http://pastebin.com/7pUtuDG0)

Comment: @pilcrow what does it mean to run it within the CGI environment? I haven't worked with CGI before.

Comment: @ikegami I included the output in my post. I removed the `ls -ld` command but kept the rest of the script.

Comment: Okay. I'll add it back in. The whole `/www/my/lib` path is actually a substitution for my employer's domain name. That's why I removed it. I'll substitute it with the domain name.

Comment: @ikegami i see what you are saying. I updated my post again to point out my index page, which redirects to the `login.cgi` script. Does my new update shed any light on the issue?

Comment: The issue is this: When I open index.html in my web browser, I get the error message I first alluded to in my post, `Can't locate conn.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /www/my/lib, etc.)`.

Comment: When you ran ikegami's script, did you run it as the webserver user or as yourself?

Comment: I ran it as myself, not as the webserver user. How can I figure out who the webserver user is?

Comment: It's a CGI script. Point your browser to it. If you want to do any substitutions in what you show us, consistently replace all instances of each word for another word (e.g. all meow.com => foo.com, all admin => someuser)

Comment: @ikegami When I point my browser to your script I get an Internal Server Error. `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.`

Comment: @ikegami Even when I only run the first 6 lines of your script, up to but **not** including the `ls -ld` command, I get the internal server error.

Comment: @ktm5124 Check your webserver's error log to see exactly why you're getting the error. If you get it only running the first six lines of ikegami's script, it's almost certainly a permissions or webserver configuration issue (e.g. the script doesn't have execute permissions).